# why output of lscpi is inconsistent with respect to BAR

Tags: linux, pci

Below is my output of `lspci -xxxx -vvvv -nn`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter [80ee:beef] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap- 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 18
    Region 0: Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Kernel driver in use: vboxvideo
00: ee 80 ef be 07 00 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00
10: 08 00 00 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
20: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
30: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0b 01 00 00
40: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
50: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
60: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
70: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
80: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
90: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
a0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
b0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
c0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
d0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
e0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
f0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Specifically I want to ask about the following lines:

```
    Region 0: Memory at e0000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
```

and

```
10: 08 00 00 e0 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Based on [this (look at section 12.1.3)](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-12-sect-1) the value of `BAR0` should be `e0000008` and not `e0000000`, i.e. the last byte should be `08` and not `00`, like it says in the description of `Region 0`. Why is it this way? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The low 4 bits are not actually part of the address. That particular bit (bit #3 with value 0x08) is the bit that marks the region as prefetchable.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_configuration_space#Bus_enumeration or http://wiki.osdev.org/PCI#Base_Address_Registers or just do a web search for "PCI configuration space header"